# Wait until pdf file is checked by virus scan

Tags: c++, .net, winapi

I've a Windows client program which creates pdf files for sending them using some other tool.
My problem is: after creation of the pdf file it usually will be blocked by virus Scanners. Sometimes this checking and blocking of the file takes too Long, so the mail program can't access the file.

So I want to delay the mail sending until the file is called clear - how can I check/wait for this?

Comment: Just keep trying until it's not blocked.

Comment: I just call some external program which is doing the rest. This external tool is not programmed by me and I can't change it.

Comment: So don't call the tool until you've confirmed that the PDF file is accessible.

Comment: Duh, right. Too obvious :) - maybe you can put this down as an answer so I can check it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wait until the PDF file is accessible before you call the tool.